# Basic caching question

Tags: jquery, json, caching

I am displaying data from JSON file (on another server) on my site with jquery.

How should I go about caching? Caching in jquery or caching the JSON files?

Can you point me in the right direction?

Polling and updating the JSON file once per hour would be enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem you're trying to solve is data that might be used by multiple different pages that you don't want to have to re-request more than once an hour.

If the data is not too large, you could save it in a cookie and set a one hour expiration on the cookie.

If this is all in one page, then you can just keep track of the last time you requested the data.

If the data is not small enough for a cookie and is across pages, you could look into HTML5 local storage which would be an optimization that would only work in modern browsers and fall back to requesting a new copy of the data when local storage was not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Caching in jQuery won't help you much if there are multiple clients or the pages are refreshed.
Caching the JSON files' contents on the server side might improve performance as the files are not read, only the server memory.

Comment: Thanks! What's the best way to cache them locally?

Comment: You can store them in a ConcurrentHashMap for example, in which the key is the identifier and the value is the JSON (whatever type of representation you're using). You both retrieve and update the values in the map.